# A Remark in Gouvea's "$p$-adic Numbers: An Introduction" on Reciprocity

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, p-adic-number-theory

We have just finished proving, using Hasse-Minkowski, the following:

Let $a, b, c$ be pairwise coprime squarefree integers. Then

$$aX^2 + bY^2 + cZ^2 = 0$$

has nontrivial solutions in $\mathbb Q$ iff the following holds:

1. $a, b, c$ are not all positive or not all negative.
2. For each odd prime $p$ dividing $a$, there exists $r \in \mathbb Z$
   with $b + r^2c \equiv 0 \ \mod \ p$, and similarly for the primes
   dividing $b$ and $c$.
3. If $a, b, c$ are all odd, then there are two of them whose sum is
   divisible by 4.
4. If $a$ is even, then either $b + c$ or $a + b + c$ is divisible by 8
   (similarly if $b$ or $c$ is even).

The author then notes that Cassels' Local Fields book has a proof that does not use condition 1, which suggests that a solution in $\mathbb Q_p$ for each $p$ guarantees a solution in $\mathbb R$, which makes us wonder if the behavior of this equation locally at $p$ for all but one prime $p \leq \infty$ determines the behavior at the final prime. Gouvea says this is true, vaguely mentions that it follows from "Reciprocity," and says nothing more. What, in a general sense, is going on here, and what does Reciprocity have to do with all this?

Comment: see   another Cassels book, Rational Quadratic Forms. Pages 80-82. The note after Corollary says that there are conditions modulo 8  that can be omitted if we say ahead of time that the form is indefinite.

Comment: I can add this:  from the global relation for the Hilbert symbol, pages 46 and 76:  a positive ternary form is anisotropic for an  **odd**   number of primes. An indefinite form   for an **even**  number of primes. Here we are including the prime $\infty.$

Comment: The term you should look up is "Hilbert reciprocity".  See, for instance, Chapter 3 of Tim Curry's senior thesis: https://production.wordpress.uconn.edu/alozano/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/2014/01/Curry_Thesis_May_2014.pdf.  Hilbert reciprocity is equivalent to quadratic reciprocity (over $\mathbf Q$, say), as each implies the other. See Theorem 3.5.2 at that link.  (Theorem 4.6.8 is an analogue of that equivalence for $\mathbf Q(i)$.)